# maven Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: maven

i use maven like

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>chinahighway.InitHighWay</mainClass>
                            -->入口类名
                        </manifest> 
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

all work right.
but i want to add some local jar to class path,so i modify like

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>chinahighway.InitHighWay</mainClass>
                            -->入口类名
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>D:\chinahighway\beyondbjdbc\iijdbc</Class-Path>
                            <Class-Path>D:\chinahighway\beyondbjdbc\hibernate-beyondb</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

after `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

java -jar ....

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   chinahighway/InitHighWay

how to solve it and can add the jar to the classpath?
plz help me and thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `jar` is not the `groupId-artifactId-version.jar`
you should add

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>beyondb</groupId>
        <artifactId>iijdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:\chinahighway\beyondbjdbc\iijdbc.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>beyondb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:\chinahighway\beyondbjdbc\hibernate-beyondb.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

this will generate `hibernate-1.jar` and `iijdbc-1.jar`,
and create the following directories

[image: created directories]

and delete the added and add

```
    <repositories>
            <!--other repositories if any -->
            <repository>
                <id>project.local</id>
                <name>project</name>
                <url>file:D:\wyr\chinahighway\highway\src\main\resources\rep</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>beyondb</groupId>
                <artifactId>iijdbc</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>beyondb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

this will solve your problem.
[Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ingres.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>iijdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.2-3.4.10</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/iijdbc.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks,but it prompt Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcepti
on: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path r
esource [conf/beyondbjpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exceptio
n is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable
 to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.Beyondb2Dialect] as strategy

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>chinahighway.InitHighWay</mainClass>
                            -->入口类名
                        </manifest>
                         <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>lib/iijdbc.jar</Class-Path>
                            <Class-Path>lib/hibernate-beyondb.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries> 
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

[image]